# I want to use Parity SCALE codec in Solidity? Is there any implementation of scale codec to decode bytes?

Tags: smart-contract, contracts, scale-codec, substrate-node, solidity

I want to decode bytes on the Solidity side that was decoded with scale codec.
Is the any implementation of `scale codec` (decode) on the Solidity side?

Comment: I believe this may be the opposite that you're asking for but may still be helpful: https://github.com/paritytech/ethereum-xcm-v3/blob/main/src/utils/ScaleCodec.sol

Comment: thanks. it opposite. but useful. thanks.

Comment: See also https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-messages-sol/blob/6f20950e445e6a63a96d0119c51679220ce2ff1d/contracts/bridge/src/utils/ScaleCodec.sol#L3